# Indexing and slicing structured ndarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, record

Now I'm trying to understand possible ways to index `numpy` structured arrays, and I kinda get stuck with it. Just a couple of simple examples:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(zip(range(5), range(5, 10)), dtype=[('a', int), ('b', int)])

arr[0] # first row (record)
arr[(0,)] # the same, as expected

arr['a'] # field 'a' of each record
arr[('a',)] # "IndexError: unsupported iterator index" ?!

arr[1:3] # second and third rows (records)
arr[1:3, 'a'] # "ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'a'" ?!
arr['a', 1:3] # same error
arr[..., 'a'] # here too...
arr['a', ...] # and here
```

So, two subquestions arise:

- Why is the result for a plain value (`'a'` in this case) different from the corresponding singleton `tuple` (`('a',)`)?
- Why the last four lines raise the error? And, probably more important, how to get the slice `arr['a'][1:3]` with a single slice? As you can see, obvious `arr['a', 1:3]` doesn't work.

I also observed the indexing behavior for built-in `list` and non-structured `ndarray`, but couldn't find such issues there: putting a single value in a tuple doesn't change anything, and of course indexing like `arr[1, 1:3]` for plain `ndarray` works as expected. Given that, should the errors in my example be considered as bugs in `numpy`?

Comment: I guess you could post a feature request on [the numpy's git](https://github.com/numpy/numpy)

Comment: Arrays like this are most useful when the fields are a mix of types and byte lengths.  In your case the fields are all the same type, and can just as well be represented by a plain `ndarray`.  All the structure adds is the ability to 'index' values with names.  A dictionary `{'a':0, 'b':1}` or variable assignments `a,b=0,1` should work just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, fields are not the same thing as dimensions - although your array `arr` has two fields and five rows, numpy actually treats it as one-dimensional (it has shape `(5,)`). Second, tuples have a special status when used as indices into numpy arrays. When you put a tuple inside the square indexing brackets, numpy interprets it as a sequence of indices into the corresponding dimensions of the array. In the special case where you have nested tuples, each inner tuple is treated as a sequence of indices into that dimension (as if it were a `list`).

Since fields don't count as dimensions, when you index it with `arr[('a',)]`, numpy interprets `'a'` as an index into the rows of `arr`. The `IndexError` is therefore raised because strings aren't a valid type for indexing into a dimension of an array (what is the 'a'th row?).

The same thing happens when you try `arr['a', 1:3]`, because this is equivalent to indexing with the tuple `('a', slice(1, 3, None))`. The comma between `'a'` and `1:3` is what makes it a tuple, regardless of the lack of brackets. Again, numpy tries to index into the rows of `arr` with `'a'`, which is invalid. However, even if both elements were valid index types, you would still get an `IndexError`, since the length of your tuple (2) is greater than the number of dimensions in `arr` (1).

`arr['a'][1:3]` and `arr[1:3]['a']` are both perfectly valid ways to index a slice of a field.

Comment: Yes, actually it answers the question, and in the same time ruins my hopes on consistent behaviour (I hoped I had missed something)... This is _very_ unintuitive for a user, being the only place in both standard library and numpy where passing a singleton tuple as index instead of a plain value totaly changes the result (the second issue kinda arises from this fact, too). I'll probably post a feature request for numpy, but this also can be thought of as a bug - due to totally inconsistent behavior. Why not just treat fields as an additional dimension, or just allow them in such cases...

Comment: Are you asking for a fundamental change in how the array data is stored and accessed, or just a superficial change in notation?  Would you change operations on dimensions like `reshape` and `swapaxes`?

Comment: I think it would be an ungodly mess - you'd need to make fields into a 'special' dimension which required a totally different syntax for indexing (`arr['foo':'bar']` obviously would not make sense). It would totally break `.reshape()`, `.ravel()` etc. if the fields contained heterogeneous data types.

Comment: `arr['a'][1:3]` is usually preferable, though.

Comment: @seberg Is there some particular reason for this? I didn't notice much difference in indexing performance between the two methods even for a `(10000,)` array with 1000 random `float64` fields.

Comment: For assignments the other way around has some funnier things as far as I remember, while at least for one field, that way around is always clean.